# getting error in installing Prerequisites wxWidgets "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, ubuntu-20.04

i'm following https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started install guide for wxWidgets.

when i'm installing Prerequisites getting error:

#### command:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev
```

#### error:

[image]

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: why not install `libwxgtk`? This will bring in all dependencies...

Comment: What if you start with `sudo apt install build-essential`?

Comment: @lgor i have tried that it's showing `pradeep@7:~/wx/wxWidgets-3.0.5/gtk-build$ sudo apt-get install libwxgtk
[sudo] password for pradeep: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libwxgtk
`

Comment: @Ripi2 i have also tried with that command `pradeep@7:~/wx/wxWidgets-3.0.5/gtk-build$ sudo apt install build-essential
[sudo] password for pradeep: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.`

Comment: @sutharp777, which OS are you on? It looks like you are on Linux (Ubuntu), but the error indicates that you are on Windows. So, which one is it? You might also play with the package name `libwxGTK`, `libwx`, `libWX`. Or if you are working on GNOME - just configure and compile.

Comment: using `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`

Comment: i got the answer, thank you every one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### run

```sh
sudo apt-cache search libwxgt*
```

it output some packages name.
than try to install one by one all the packages.

### output

```sh
libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 media library runtime)
libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 media library development)
libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 webview library runtime)
libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 webview library development)
libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 runtime)
libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 development)
```

for example

```
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5
...
```

and so on.